# My Shift, Caps Lock, and Enter keys are acting up

Tags: keyboard

my shift doesn't even work.
when i try to use caPS LOCK, IT CREAtes a LETTER 
'A' or 'a'
for example; AaAaAaAaAaA here i aM CONTINUOUSLY PRESSING CAps lock.
when e
ver i press a, IT SWITCHES TO LOWER CAse to upper caSE OR 
VISE 
VERSA.
when i press enter, it goes on the ne`Xt line, but it creaTES A quotaTION 
when i press the quotaTION, like so;
' IT IS THE SAme outcome. it maKES THE QUOTAtion aND THEN IT GOES ON THE NE`xT LINE.
WHEN I PRESS 
'X', IT LOOKS LIKE; `X. 
e
ven some of the aLT CODES Are messes up. if i try to do th aT SYMBOL IN EMAil aDRESSES, WHICH IS Alt 64, it creaTES; ó 
And the plus sign is aLT 43, IT CREAtes; τ
'pleaSE I NEED HELP

Comment: Hahahaha!!. I would edit this post but it's too hilarious! Friend, I would just try another keyboard. Or at least ask the question from a functioning computer.

Comment: How come the question title has no typos or case changes?

Comment: i tried to maKE THE TITLE LOOK PRESENAtaBLE At leaST And thaT TOOK TOO LONG TO DO ESPECIAlly the uppercaSE LETTERS SINCE  IT WOULD Add raNDOM ;A;s everywhere